Why this code doesn't sent a message to me?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ConnectDeluxe</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS-styling */
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        .chatbox {
            background-image: url('https://webtinq.nl/chat-deluxe/afbeeldingen/daniel-korpai-r73OFSry5AI-unsplash.jpg');
            height: 300px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .error {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script>
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "BBlTZ10mtqqo4VI5pwsvXnPNUGL2MD755xjKucGkm8EOlL-NySJXCVA-AgIuzvl4BW1rEG4TXfajqCm0dLB3r-Q",
            authDomain: "connectdeluxe-5404f.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "connectdeluxe-5404f",
            storageBucket: "connectdeluxe-5404f.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "502412264937",
            appId: "1:502412264937:web:7fa09b1ec233f1094d3778",
            measurementId: "G-LGSL200SY7"
        };

        // Firebase initialisatie
        const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        // Firebase Messaging importeren
        const messaging = app.messaging(); // Gebruik app.messaging() in plaats van firebase.messaging()

        // JavaScript-functionaliteit
        var phoneNumber = "";
        var receiverNumber = "";

        function addPhoneNumber() {
            phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumberInput').value;
            if (phoneNumber.trim() === "") {
                document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerText = "Voer eerst je telefoonnummer in.";
                document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = "block";
                return;
            }
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberInput').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberLabel').innerText = "Je telefoonnummer: " + phoneNumber;
            document.getElementById('receiverInputContainer').style.display = "block";
        }

        function startChat() {
            receiverNumber = document.getElementById('receiverInput').value;
            if (receiverNumber.trim() === "") {
                alert("Voer eerst het telefoonnummer van de ontvanger in.");
                return;
            }
            if (receiverNumber === phoneNumber) {
                alert("Je kunt geen berichten naar jezelf sturen.");
                return;
            }
            document.getElementById('receiverInputContainer').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('chatbox').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('messageInput').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('messageInput').focus();
            document.getElementById('messageInput').placeholder = "Bericht naar " + receiverNumber;
            document.getElementById('messageInput').setAttribute("title", "Bericht naar " + receiverNumber);
            document.getElementById('messageInput').setAttribute("data-receiver", receiverNumber);
            document.getElementById('messageInput').value = "";
            document.getElementById('messageInput').focus();
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('sendMessageButton').style.display = "block"; // Hier wordt de verstuurknop weergegeven
        }

        async function sendMessage() {
            var message = document.getElementById('messageInput').value;
            var receiver = receiverNumber; // Gebruik de opgeslagen ontvanger

            if (message.trim() === "" || receiver.trim() === "") {
                alert("Voer eerst een bericht en het telefoonnummer van de ontvanger in.");
                return;
            }

            try {
                // FCM-token ophalen van de ontvanger
                const token = await messaging.getToken();

                // Bericht verzenden via Firebase Cloud Messaging
                const payload = {
                    data: {
                        message: message,
                        receiver: receiver
                    },
                    token: token
                };

                await messaging.send(payload);
                console.log('Bericht verzonden via Firebase Cloud Messaging!');

                // Bericht weergeven in de chatbox
                displayMessage("Jij", message);
                alert('Bericht verzonden via Firebase Cloud Messaging!');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Fout bij verzenden van bericht:', error);
                alert('Er is een fout opgetreden bij het verzenden van het bericht.');
            }
        }

        // Nieuwe functie om berichten weer te geven in de chatbox
        function displayMessage(sender, message) {
            var chatbox = document.getElementById('chatbox');
            var messageElement = document.createElement('div');
            messageElement.innerText = sender + ": " + message;
            chatbox.appendChild(messageElement);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ConnectDeluxe</h1>
    <div id="phoneNumberContainer">
        <h2>Voer je telefoonnummer in:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumberInput">
        <button onclick="addPhoneNumber()">Toevoegen</button>
        <p class="error" id="errorMessage" style="display: none;"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="phoneNumberLabel" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="receiverInputContainer" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Chat met:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="receiverInput" placeholder="Telefoonnummer van de ontvanger">
        <button onclick="startChat()">Start</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="chatbox" class="chatbox" style="display: none;"></div>
    <input type="text" id="messageInput" style="display: none;">
    <button id="sendMessageButton" onclick="sendMessage()" style="display: none;">Versturen</button> <!-- Dit is de verstuurknop -->
</body>
</html>


"That's my code. Nothing happens when I try to send a message. I had written some code, but it's not working."
"I expected a message to be sent to my phone because I entered my number. I wanted Firebase to make it possible and send a message. But that failed, so now I'm asking for your help.""Could it possibly be something in my code causing the issue?"

it is not good idea to show everyone api key that your code uses
